# Access filter result Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, filter

How can I access `filteredArray` in my .ts component? Because right now it is accessible only inside `ng-container`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(userList | filter: 'name' : value) as filteredArray">
    <tr *ngFor="let user of filteredArray">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.group}}</td>
    </tr>

    <div>Count: {{ filteredArray.length }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

How can I modify the code in order to obtain what I want? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Then you can provide your pipe like a service and inject in your component, `transform` in the component `ts` and use the result in `HTML`

Comment: Good idea, I will try that right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Avoid doing the following.... but it works for demo purposes**

Create a component (e.g. `demo-element.component.ts`) that takes a single `@Input() value:any`

Add this new component as the first child of the `<ng-container>`, and give it a template reference `#containerRef` e.g.:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(userList | filter: 'name' : value) as filteredArray">
    <demo-element #containerRef [value]="filteredArray"></demo-element>
```

In your main component, add

```
@ViewChild('containerRef') ref;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.filteredArray = this.ref.value; // Terrible pattern, but answers the question:-)
}
```

Comment: Just for the future readers: this _should_ be the accepted answer because it answers the question indeed, but if you really care for your app, proceed to an explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53562772/2131286. Great thinking, @Drenai!

Comment: I upvoted your answer and marked this one. But your answer is great too. Thank you both.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question directly: **it's not possible** the way you describe it. But read on.

Pipes (sometimes still called "filters") should be used only to format data, i.e. prepare it in a human-readable form. For example, the build-in `date` pipe can be used to transform an ISO string to a string such as "March 21st, 1995", which is how a human from the USA might expect to read the date.

The way you're using pipes is not recommended, precisely because of the question you have. You've essentially put application logic inside a template, which is an anti-pattern and beats the purpose of having easy-to-read declarative templates, which Angular uses in order to figure out how to update DOM.

You should move the filtering logic back to the class. For example, instead of setting `this.userList = xxx`, you could have a function which you call every time, such as `this.changeUserList(xxx)`.

```
changeUserList (list) {
  this.userList = list
  this.filteredArray = list.filter(...)
}
```

You can put this logic in a setter as well, which allows you to run custom code when you write the usual `this.userList = list`, but you'll need a separate (usually prefixed private) property on the class where you'd *actually* store the value. It's not really a limitation since you can also have a trivial getter, so you can still us `this.userList` normally as a getter without having to remember to use `this._userList`, essentially tucking this away as the get/set pair's implementation detail.

```
private _userList

public set userList (list) {
  this._userList = list
  this.filteredArray = list.filter(...)
}

public get userList (list) { return this._userList }
```

Observables could really come in handy here as well, since you could just `rx.map` the `userList$` to `filteredArray$` with an `Array#filter`.

```
public userList$
public filteredArray$ = this.userList$.pipe(map(arr => arr.filter(...))
```

Then in the template, you can use the `async` pipe.

```
*ngIf="filteredArray$ | async as filteredArray"
```

Comment: I know it's not efficient, but it's just for testing. In time, I will modify and I will stop using pipes. Good answer tho.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this below code will help you.

```
<div class="rsrvtn_blk" *ngIf="(items | fSearch:firstname) as filteredItems">
  <div class="col-md-3 pl-0" *ngFor="let item of filteredItems">
    // you can display the filtered content here
  </div>
</div>
```